# Visual Studio 2022 fails to properly detect Auth0 authentication package

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor

I am working on a project that is using Blazor WebAssembly. Right now, I am trying to set up authentication in the project. Before adding the Auth0 authentication package, the project builds and runs perfectly fine. However, as soon as I add the Auth0 authentication package, I get a build error:

"NETSDK1082 There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'."

Because of this error, I am unable to use any Auth0 functionality. Putting `using Auth0.AspNetCore.Authentication;` at the top of the Program.cs file gives me the following error: "CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Auth0' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". The only fix suggested by Visual Studio is to remove the line entirely.

I noticed that under Dependencies --> Packages, the Auth0.AspNetCore.Authentication (1.0.4) package has a yellow warning triangle, but hovering over the triangle does nothing, and none of the right-click menu options provide me any indication of what this means.

I have been following https://auth0.com/blog/what-is-blazor-tutorial-on-building-webapp-with-authentication/ as a tutorial, and the "Integrating with Auth0" section is where I run into trouble. I have tried redoing the tutorial, deleting and re-cloning the Git repo, running `dotnet restore` in the Developer PowerShell, and browsing for answers on Stack Overflow without any success.

My project uses .NET 6.0, Auth0.AspNetCore.Authentication 1.0.4 (the problematic package), Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly 6.0.8, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer 6.0.8, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 6.0.9, and Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.2.0. How can I get Visual Studio to fully recognize the Auth0 authentication package, so I can use it?

**UPDATE**
It turns out that I was using the wrong blog tutorial. Zsolt Bendes's comment has the correct blog for my needs. https://auth0.com/blog/securing-blazor-webassembly-apps/

Comment: The yellow warning triangle means  package is not compatible, The error message may caused by this reason. I try to install all the nuget package you mentioned before, But the packages are  compatible, You can try to clean your project and rebuild.

Comment: That package is not meant for webassembly. Try the other blog https://auth0.com/blog/securing-blazor-webassembly-apps/

Comment: Thank you for referring me to the correct blog! The package mentioned there is working without any problems so far.